# Does this alternative model require more data points for regression?

Tags: multiple-regression

*I will preface this question by admitting my limited statistical background. If my technical jargon is off, please feel free to correct me*

---

We're looking to improve our current linear, quadratic model (with interactions) for $Y$ that requires three predictors, $a$, $b$ and $c$:

$$ Y = f(a, b, c) = \beta_1a^2 + \beta_2b^2 + \beta_3c^2 + \beta_4ab ... + \beta_n$$

There is a (physics-oriented) suggestion to use an alternative approach which involves modelling parameter $d$ using a quadratic fit for $a$, $b$ and $c$, and use $d$ as a predictor for $Y$:

$$ d = g(a, b, c) = \gamma_1a^2 + \gamma_2b^2 + \gamma_3c^2 + \gamma_4ab + \gamma_5ac... + \gamma_n $$
$$ Y = h(a, b, d) = \xi_1a^2 + \xi_2b^2 + \xi_3d^2 + \xi_4ab + \xi_5ad... + \xi_n$$

***Some additional notes***

- Due to the unwanted expense of testing, it is desired to keep the dataset required for regression as low as possible.
- The data for $d$ is already available in the existing dataset
- In our very preliminary testing, the alternative model has a higher $R^2$ value over the existing approach.

***There are two opinions within our group***

1. No additional data samples are required since the number of unknowns ($\xi_1, \xi_2...\xi_n$) has not changed
2. More data samples are required to prevent overfitting ("preserve the quality of the regression") because the alternative model now has higher order terms ($a^4, a^2b, b^4, b^2a$)

***The big question here is, which opinion (if any) is right, and why?***

Comment: I assume that in the equation for h, the 'c' in the third term is a typo.

Comment: It looks like in both cases you are projecting $y$ onto the space of $a,b,c$, just in the second case you do an intermediate step of projecting $y$ onto $d$ onto $a,b,c$. I don't think your results should be different in the two cases and it looks like including $d$ is superfluous. But maybe I am not getting it right.

Comment: @Richard Close: but including $d$ in the second model makes it a *quartic* regression.  In effect, it extends the first model with $n$ additional parameters, but most of them are not identifiable (since $\xi_1+\gamma_1=\beta_1$, *etc*).

Comment: @whuber, thanks. The equations have been edited recently, removing $c$ from the second equation, but probably that would not be a game changer in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get the gamma-parameters from? If you got those from the data, even indirectly, then that means that those still 'count' as extra parameters. So if you had had gotten completely different data from the very beginning, would the gamma-parameters be any different?
If the gamma-parameters are based on some prior theory that is independent of the measurements, you are doing the same quadratic regression, only you swap one variable for another. That shouldn't change things.

edit: Ah, it took some time before I understood the question. So we have $a$, $b$ and $c$ as measured, independent variables and $d$ and $Y$ as dependent variables. Now the question is whether instead of using $a$, $b$ and $c$ to fit $Y$, we could fit $d$ first and then fit $Y$ using $a$, $b$ and $d$.
There are 2 ways to fit this problem. First you always have to fit $d$ using $a$, $b$ and $c$. This will give a fitted value $\widetilde{d}$ for each (training)-input. Now the question is, do we fit $Y$ with $a$, $b$ and $d$ or with $a$, $b$ and $\widetilde{d}$?
In the first option we just have n-degrees of freedom in fitting our model. Since we aren't basing our model on $\gamma$, but only on measured data, we don't get any extra possibility of overfitting. However the downside is that when we start making predictions with our model, we are going to replace $d$ with $\widetilde{d}$. Since there is the real possibility that our approximation $\widetilde{d}$ is not perfect, this is going to be an extra source of error. So when testing our model on the test-set, we need to use $\widetilde{d}$ and we expect that this will give a larger than usual difference between the error on the training-set and the test-set.
We could also fit $Y$ using $a$, $b$ and $\widetilde{d}$. This way the model can account for and possibly correct for any errors made when approximating $d$. However this is a source for overfitting. If the distribution of $a$'s and/or $b$'s is biased, this bias is going to affect the learning process twice. First in approximating $d$ and then in approximating $Y$. More importantly, the bias in $a$ and $b$ is going to be exactly the same both times. So here you do need to be more careful with overfitting and maybe apply some regularization or get more training examples.

Comment: To answer your question about the $\gamma$ values, they are derived from the same dataset and can be thought of as a second $Y$.

Comment: Then you definitely have more parameters than just the 'n'. Do you fit the gamma-parameters first before you do anything with the xi's? Or do you combine fitting both sets of parameters (either fitting both at the same time or iterating between fitting one and then the other)?

Comment: It's $\gamma$ first, then $\xi$

Comment: And what cost function do you use to optimize $\gamma$? How do you distinguish a good value of d from a bad one?

Comment: I think we used least-squares regression (whatever is utilized by R's `lm` function). As for good versus bad, we found the error of the $\gamma$ model to be acceptable in the course of our testing; we're not considering it to be a perfect substitute.

Comment: But for regression you need training examples, how do you obtain the target-values for d in those training examples?

Comment: $d$ is one of several response parameters that come out of the same test. So for each experiment, a single combination of $a$, $b$ and $c$ has a corresponding $d$ and $Y$.

Comment: So d is a measured value/feature and you want to replace it by an approximated value for 'd', training the $\gamma$'s to generate this approximation? Then my question would be, why not use the original d's in the calculation of the $\xi$'s?

Comment: It's because $d$ is a dependent variable; the independent variables are $a$, $b$ and $c$. Since $d$ belongs to the output space and not the input space, we have to approximate it.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. See my edit